# Phonegap build and config.xml

Tags: android, cordova

I'm currently using phonegap build to build my mobile application created in html file and some css and javascript file, What i want is to add a config.xml file to use some preferences to my app. but the problem is i don't know where will i put my config.xml file correctly. below is the file structure of my app

```
HelloWorld
 - index.html
 - css
   - style.css
 - js
   - script.js
 - app
   - www
     - config.xml
```

currently thats the file structure of my app, i upload it in phonegap build then build the apk for it. My main reason why i add a config.xml file is to get rid of the bounce effect when i scroll up or down in my app. i use this preference to solve that issue, but the problem is, i don't know if my config.xml file is in proper location

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

Comment: I use the config.xml file in <your project dir>/www/.  The one inside the platform directories (android or ios) is overwritten every time you compile the project

Answer (score 0):

```
the problem is i don't know where will i put my config.xml file correctly.
```

You should put `config.xml` inside `res>xml>config.xml`

Like below(**File Structure**)

```
     res
     xml folder
     config.xml
```